# Hibernate Collection mapping, Refactoring

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

The title may not be very descriptive.

I have recently come across a problem with Hibernate many-to-many collections using Link tables. In the application we were using List and whenever we delete or insert an entry from the collection, hibernate deletes all the entries from the link table and proceeds to add them back (either with the inserted new entry or without the deleted entry). This as you can see is a performance nightmare.

So I wanted to convert all these relationships to Set. I wanted to do that without changing the interface (unfortunately the client code is distributed across and method to Set is a no-no).

I tried changing the attributes to Set, without changing the signature of the Getters and Setters (internally mapping list to set and vice-versa), but hibernate still considers the mapping a bag (Which makes sense.)

Do anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Hibernate has a special collection for many-to-many associations; the [idbag](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-idbag). Why not use that?

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I would like to use Set since it makes more sense. (I want an Hashed Collection for improved performance in my application outside the hibernate context.). Thank you for the IDBag idea. I might just use it if I cannot find a viable alternative.

Comment: You can use `private` getters and setters for Hibernate and `public` getters and setters for your domain. That way you can use a `Set` internally and copy across in the hibernate accessors.